# Компиляция документа в отдельный файл

Tags: latex

Есть шаблон документа в LaTeX, который необходимо заполнять и компилировать. Но при компиляции генерируется один файл с именем документа и переписывается.

То есть при выполнении команды `xelatex filename.tex` генерируется `filename.pdf`. А необходимо что-то вроде `otherfilename_datetime.pdf`.

`xelatex --help` ничем не помог - то ли я не нашёл нужной опции, то ли не понял, как эта опция работает.

Дистрибутив: TeXLive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё таки, информация в `xelatex --help` была, хоть и неочевидной.

Решение: `xelatex -jobname=otherfilename filename.tex`. В моём случае мне ещё понадобилось скомпилировать в другую директорию (чтобы все выходящие файлы не смешивались в кучу), поэтому команда приняла следующий вид:

`xelatex -jobname=otherfilename -output-directory=../otherdir filename.tex`